# Lazy property of objects in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, lazy-evaluation

I have an object, Catalogue, that represents the catalogue of a manufacturer. Catalogues have filemanagers that help access the content of huge flat files containing list of products and their characteristics.

I often manipulate Catalogue objects not necessarily to access the huge files, so I don't want to load the file all the time. I have design my file manager to be a lazy-evaluated property.

```
class Catalogue:
  def __init__(self, manufaturer, catalogue_filename):
    self.manufacturer = manufacturer
    self.catalogue_filename = catalogue_filename

  @property
  def filemanager(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_filemanager'):
      self._filemanager = load_and_index_huge_file(self.catalogue_filename)
    return self._filemanager
```

All this is well and good. I often use those catalogues in lists.
So let's say I retrieve a list in database:

```
cat_list = get_all_catalogues()
```

And then I access a filemanager directly from the list

```
print cat_list[2].filemanager.dosomething()
```

The file is loaded and indexed (takes forever) and I have my answer. My probleme is if I do it again.

```
print cat_list[2].filemanager.dosomething()
```

The file is loaded again! I believe it is because, by indexing the list, I actually get a copy of my catalogue. Copy that is immediatly detroyed, the catalogue in the list not being modified whatsoever, so the filemanager is not loaded for him.

Is there a standard and pythonic way to deal with that? I'd like to load my filemanager for the catalogue IN the list.

Comment: "I believe it is because, by indexing the list, I actually get a copy of my catalogue." - that doesn't happen. Just passing stuff around doesn't create copies in Python. Your problem is coming from code not in the question. Can you create a [runnable, simplified example version of your code that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Probably simulate the file loading with something like `time.sleep`.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do is called caching. The lazy evaluation should be irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like you've retyped your code into your question instead of copy-pasting, leading to a number of typos that make your problem much harder to diagnose. Please don't do that. Also, check that in your real code, the `hasattr` is checking the right attribute.

Comment: @user2357112 You never know, maybe he's using one of those mythical pythons from the stone age where the def before the __init__ was optional :P

Comment: Ok my mistake. I misidentified the source of the problem by trying to over simplify it without proper investigation. The issue comes from the ORM I'm using (Django's ORM). The list is actually not a list but a QuerySet. And for some reason, the QuerySet.__getitem__ is cloning the queryset before returning the element. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L196. Not sure if I should rephrase the question (which change it's nature) or just answer it.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question: no, indexing lists does not do any kind of copying (shallow or deep). Here's some sample code to illustrate my point:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'b'):
            print "Setting self.b"
            self.b = self.a

        return self.b

test_list = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3)]

print test_list[2].b
print test_list[2].b
```

Which for me at least prints:

```
Setting self.b
3
3
```

As you can see, the code inside `if not hasattr...` is only called once.